# C - Tower of Hanoi - Display the content of each peg for each iteration of the algorithm using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I'm new to programming and currently one of my assignments is to successfully write a programme for the Tower of Hanoi problem. I have got a programme already working however, I would like to be able to see after each iteration what each of the peg's contain, however I'm not quite sure how to implement the arrays/2D arrays here.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void towerOfHanoi(int numberOfDisks, char source, char destination, char aux)
{
  char ArrayA[100];
  char ArrayB[100];
  char ArrayC[100];
  if (numberOfDisks == 1)
  {
    printf("Move disk 1 from peg %c to peg %c \n", source, destination);
    return;
  }
  towerOfHanoi(numberOfDisks - 1, source, aux, destination);
  printf("Move disk %d from peg %c to peg %c\n", numberOfDisks, source, destination);
  towerOfHanoi(numberOfDisks - 1, aux, destination, source);    
}  



int main()                                    
{
  int numberOfDisks;
  char startingPoint; 
  printf("Enter the amount of Disks: \n");
  scanf("%d", &numberOfDisks);
  printf("Which peg would you like to start from? (A rightside, B centre, C, leftside\n");
  scanf("\n%c", &startingPoint); 
  if (startingPoint == 'A')
  {
    printf("The sequence of moves invloved in the tower of hanoi are: \n");
    towerOfHanoi(numberOfDisks, 'A', 'B', 'C');
  }
  else if (startingPoint == 'B')
  {
    printf("The sequence of moves invloved in the tower of hanoi are: \n");
    towerOfHanoi(numberOfDisks, 'B', 'A', 'C');
  }
  else if (startingPoint == 'C')
  {
    printf("The sequence of moves invloved in the tower of hanoi are: \n");
    towerOfHanoi(numberOfDisks, 'C', 'A', 'B');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: Yes most of it, of course I had to look up the algorithom to understand the problem and found out the you could implent it either throught iteration or recursion. My problem is I'm not sure how to implement the arrays to store the data after each iteration.

Comment: to make the code much more robust,  after getting the starting location (A,B, or C)  then 1) pass the value through `toupper()`  2) check the value is actually `A` or `B` or `C`.

Comment: BTW:  involved is spelled `involved` not `invloved`

Comment: to avoid stack overflows, suggest limiting the maximum number of disks as that will limit the depth of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way to be able to display the contents of each of (A,B,C).

1. use doubly linked lists of nodes where each node contains the number of the associated disk
2. decide how to display the linked list contents
3. moving a disk then becomes removing the first node from the source linked list and inserting it into the first position of the destination linked list
4. Notice that any specific linked list could contain anywhere from 0 to `n` nodes.